# Javascript Random Number limit characters - selenium

Tags: javascript, random, selenium

New to javascript - I'm trying to generate random user ID's for my selenium test scripts. I'm using this line for my value:

```
javascript{Math.floor(Math.random()*11111)}
```

However, one particular field requires a value with exactly 8 numbers - is there a way to write this so that it returns an exact number of digits?

Thanks!!

Comment: Generate a number between 0 and 9999999 and then add 10000000 to it ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*90000000) + 10000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function r() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9.9999999);
}

function sequence() {
  var n = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    n += r();
  }
  return n;
}

sequence();
```